# How can I use fonts from one folder in different projects using webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, fonts

Hello I'm having a project which holds multiple projects and I wanted to reduce the size of the project by putting all the assets that are shared in a folder. For example each project had it's own fonts folder and this led to having the fonts imported like three times. So this is my project structure:

```
-project1
  |--subfolders
-project2
  |--subfolders
-shared
  |--fonts
  |--scss
     |--|--fonts.scss
     |--|--global.scss
```

So in the fonts folder I have my font files and in the fonts.scss I'm declaring them like this:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Cosmica',
   src: url('../fonts/Cosmica.woff2) format('woff2)
}
```

and in the global.scss which is getting imported by the other projects I'm making an import like this `@import "./fonts"`

Then when the project builds I'm getting this error `These relative modules were not found: ../fonts/Cosmica.woff2 in ./nodule_modules/css-loader...`

And this is the error that is displayed in the browser:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/Cosmica.woff2' in '/Users/blabla/projects2/src/assets/scss
```

This is what I guess does the imports of the fonts in webpack:

```
{
    test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  },
```

Any idea how to proceed? This is an existing project and I have no idea how webpack works.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Install file-loader**

```
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

**2.Add file-loader to webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'build.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'fonts/'
                    }
                }]
            }
        ],
    },
    watch: true,
};
```

Check this link out, it can help you:
https://chriscourses.com/blog/loading-fonts-webpack

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've tried the guide and I'm still getting the same error.